Pyomo Constraint
I am trying to run this constraint using pyomo and solver is IPOPT. Can somebody please help.
I have same kind of code for upper limit as well.
V_statutory_lim=[0.95, 1.05]
        def V_limit_rule_lower(model,k,s,t):
            if k=='slack':
                return pyo.Constraint.Skip
            else:
                V_nom = Bus_Vnom.loc[k, 'Vnom_pn']

                ex=model.V_mag_2[k, s, t]/(V_nom**2)
                #print("exL")
                if value(ex) < 0.95*0.95:
                    #print("RETURN")
                    #return ((V_nom * V_statutory_lim[0]) ** 2, model.V_mag_2[k, s, t])
                    return (model.V_mag_2[k, s, t]>=(V_nom * V_statutory_lim[0]) ** 2)
                    #return (model.V_mag_2[k, s, t] == V_nom ** 2)
                    #return model.V_mag_2[k, s, t] >= (V_nom * V_statutory_lim[0]) ** 2
                else:
                    return pyo.Constraint.Skip

        model.V_limits_lower_con = pyo.Constraint(model.Buses, model.Phases_abc, model.time, rule=V_limit_rule_lower)

But I get infeasible solution.
EXIT: Converged to a point of local infeasibility. Problem may be infeasible.
WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into
model.name="unknown";
- termination condition: infeasible
- message from solver: Ipopt 3.11.1\x3a Converged to a locally infeasible
point. Problem may be infeasible.
Thank you.
Help in code snippet

You probably need to delete everything here and start over with your question.  The solver says the model is infeasible.  It is certainly correct.  How is someone supposed to analyze 1 piece of the model with no data and determine why it is infeasible?  Start commenting out constraints and see if you can pin it down, or post a reproducible example that shows the problem.

This constraint is causing issue. There is something wrong in it.
